# Pinescript 5 - Ray on monthly open / high / low

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I know there are a lot of monthly open scripts, but I want one that extends the line for future months (to the right of the screen).

Most common ones use the plot method, which only plots for that particular month in the loop.

Here is what I currently have. It uses a slightly modified version of this [ray library](https://www.tradingview.com/script/WRHeq9cf-e2-Drawing-Library-Horizontal-Ray/)

```js
//@version=5
indicator("Ray Test", overlay = true)

hray(bool condition, float level, color color, bool extend = true, bool hist_lines = true, string alert_message = na, int alert_delay = 0, string style = line.style_solid, string hist_style = line.style_dashed, int width = 1, int hist_width = 1) =>
    var line[]  hrays     = array.new_line()
    var line[]  histHrays = array.new_line()
    var int     delay     = alert_delay * 60 * 1000 // MS_IN_MIN
    
    if condition
        array.push(hrays, line.new(time[1], level, time, level, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color, width = width, style = style))
    
    for [i, hray] in hrays
        float price = line.get_y1(hray)
        int   since = line.get_x1(hray)
        line.set_x2(hray, time_close)
        
        //bool broken = price < close[1] ? low <= price : high >= price
        bool broken = false

        if broken
            if hist_lines
                histHray = line.copy(hray), line.set_extend(histHray, extend.none), line.set_style(histHray, hist_style), line.set_width(histHray, hist_width), array.unshift(histHrays, histHray)
            line.delete(hray)
            
            if (time - since > delay) and (not na(alert_message))
                alert(alert_message, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
                
        else if extend
            line.set_extend(hray, extend.right) // }


/////////////
// Script
/////////////

show = dayofmonth(time) == 1 and hour(time) == 0 and second(time) == 0

hray(show, open, color.red)
```

What I am looking for is a better way to detect the month open instead of using the time dayofmonth, hour, seconds etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `ta.change(time("M"))` will return `true` when the bar is the first bar of the month. You can use:

```
show = ta.change(time("M"))
```